# Copy values from one table to another in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables `users` and `partners`. They both contain a `created_on` field but that field is new and thus empty in the `partners` table. The `partners` table also has a `user_id` and `partner_id` field. The `user_id` field is the FK to the `users` table.

I need to copy the values of the column `created_on` from the `users` tables into the `partners` table `for each` user `WHERE partners.user_id = users.id`.

I want to do that in SQL (my RDBMS is MySQL) so no PHP (if possible)

(Some pseudo code to get my problem across better)

Copying data is not good practice, I know that, but I need this for a specific case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `update`/`join`:

```
update partners p join
       users u
       on p.user_id = u.id
    set p.created_on = u.created_on;
```

Comment: And to think I had an entire course on SQL... I guess that A+ was unjustified :')

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this

```
CREATE TABLE USERS
(
user_id int,
  created_on datetime
);
CREATE TABLE PARTNERS
(
partner_id int,
user_id int,
created_on datetime
);
insert into users (user_id, created_on) values (1,"2000-1-1");
insert into users (user_id, created_on) values (2, "2001-1-1");
insert into partners (partner_id, user_id, created_on) values (10,1,null);
insert into partners (partner_id, user_id, created_on) values (11,2,null);


Update Partners p
INNER JOIN users u
on p.user_id = u.user_id
Set p.created_on = u.created_on;

select * from partners
```